# Image Preview before upload Incase of Inserting Multiple Rows in Laravel

Tags: javascript, image, laravel-8

Please the screenshot how I add more rows....

[image]

Input Field and Preview Area:

```
<td class="border-0">
 <div class="param_img_holder"></div>
</td>
<td class="border-0">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="param_img[]" value="x.pbg">
</td>
```

Preview Script:

```
         $('input[type="file"][name="param_img[]"]').val('');
        //Image preview
        $('input[type="file"][name="param_img[]"]').on('change', function(){
            var img_path = $(this).value;
            var param_img_holder = $('.param_img_holder');
            var extension = img_path.substring(img_path.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase();
            if(extension == 'jpeg' || extension == 'jpg' || extension == 'png' || extension == 'gif'|| extension == 'webp'){
                if(typeof(FileReader) != 'undefined'){
                    param_img_holder.empty();
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(e){
                        $('<img/>',{'src':e.target.result,'class':'img-fluid','style':'width:110px; height:70px; margin-bottom:10px;'}).appendTo(param_img_holder);
                    }
                    param_img_holder.show();
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
                }else{
                    $(param_img_holder).html('This browser does not support FileReader');
                }
            }else{
                $(param_img_holder).empty();
            }
        });
```

The Problem I am facing is, the first image preview is fine. But when I add one row the image is not showing .... In case of this, What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two main issues in your code.

Firstly you need to select the `.param_img_holder` element relative to the `input` which was changed, not *all* of them in the DOM. You can achieve this by using the `this` keyword to reference the `input` which triggered the event, then `closest()` to get the common `tr` and `find()`.

In addition, jQuery objects don't have a `value` property. You need to use `val()` instead.

Here's working version which includes a couple of other improvements, such as reducing `if` condition nesting, using an array to hold the valid file extensions and using CSS for styling instead of inline `style` attributes.

```js
const validExtensions = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'webp'];

$('table').on('change', '.file-input', function() {
  const $input = $(this);
  const imgPath = $input.val();
  const $imgPreview = $input.closest('tr').find('.param_img_holder');
  const extension = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

  if (typeof(FileReader) == 'undefined') {
    $imgPreview.html('This browser does not support FileReader');
    return;
  }

  if (validExtensions.includes(extension)) {
    $imgPreview.empty();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('<img/>', {
        src: e.target.result,
        class: 'img-fluid'
      }).appendTo($imgPreview);
    }
    $imgPreview.show();
    reader.readAsDataURL($input[0].files[0]);
  } else {
    $imgPreview.empty();
  }
});
```

```css
.param_img_holder {
  display: none;  
}

.param_img_holder img.img-fluid {
  width: 110px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="border-0">
      <div class="param_img_holder"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="border-0">
      <input type="file" class="form-control file-input" name="param_img[]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="border-0">
      <div class="param_img_holder"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="border-0">
      <input type="file" class="form-control file-input" name="param_img[]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```